# Surjectivity of Derivatives in infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I have a trouble about an exercise in Techniques of Variational Analysis, *Borwein, J.M., Zhu, Q.J* (Ex. 2.1.2):
Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Fréchet differentiable function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative[Fréchet_derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)). Suppose that $f$ is bounded from below on any bounded set and satisfies $$\lim_{\left \| x \right \| \to \infty} \frac{f\left (x \right )}{\left \| x \right \|}=+\infty$$ Then the range of $f'$ is dense in $X^*$.

---

By the similar method in $\mathbb{R}$, for $\gamma \in X^*$, letting $g\left ( x \right ) = f \left ( x \right ) -\langle \gamma , x \rangle $. I proved $g \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. However, I have no idea to continue or construct a sequence in the range of $f'$ converging to $\gamma$. I also don't know how to use the hypothesis that $f$ is bounded from below on any bounded set.

Comment: In a finite dimensional context, the "usual" proof would be to take $x$ as a minimizer of $g$. Then the derivative at $x$ will vanish, which yields what you want (even surjectivity). In your context, we know that $\inf_x g(x) > -\infty$ (why?) and that every minimizing sequence $(x_n)_n$ with $g(x_n) \to \inf_x g(x)$ is bounded (why?), but I don't think that the minimum is achieved in general. I am not sure how to show that $g'(x_n) \to 0$. I am not even sure if that is true. Do you want density with respect to the norm topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the conclusion by applying [Ekeland's variational principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekeland%27s_variational_principle) to $g$. (The principle ought to be discussed in that book, given its title.)

Since $g(x) = f(x)-\langle \gamma,x\rangle$ is bounded below,  for any $\epsilon>0$ you can pick $u\in X$ such that $g(u)<\inf g+\epsilon$. From Ekeland's principle you get  the existence of a point $v$ such that 
$$g(w)-g(v)\ge -\epsilon \|w-v\|\quad \text{ for all }w\tag{1}$$ 
Suppose $\|g'(v)\|>\epsilon$. Then there exists a unit vector $h$ such that $\langle g'(v), h \rangle > \epsilon$. Hence
$$
g(v-th)-g(v) = -t\langle g'(v), h \rangle + o(t)  \tag{2}
$$
which is strictly less than $ -\epsilon t$ when $t$ is small enough. This contradicts (1), proving that $\|g'(v)\| \le\epsilon$.

Thus $0$ is in the norm-closure of the range of $g'$, hence $\gamma$ is in the norm-closure of the range of $f'$.

Comment: You have a few inconsistencies in nomenclature, e.g. $f (x)<\inf\dots $ instead of $f (u) $ and "for all $v $" should be "for all $w $". Finally, I don't really see how you get the estimate for the operator norm, it seems that you only have a one-sided estimate, although you would need a two-sided one.  Could you explain?

Comment: Edited. One-sided estimate + linearity $\implies$ two-sided estimate.